# How to configure Jest for Vue app that runs via Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, jestjs, webpacker

I've got a Rails app that manages a Vue app through the Webpacker gem.

I'm having trouble setting up Jest for unit tests.  I've had to add a few new dependencies like `vue-jest` and `babel-jest`, but now I'm stuck with the problem of the tests not recognizing a new component.

When I run the `jest` command (via yarn), the test I've written fails once it encounters a new component that's imported in the component under test.

```
import AnotherComponent from './another-component.js';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

  2 | 
  3 | import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
> 4 | import ComponentUnderTest from '../src/component-under-test.vue';
    | ^
  5 |
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```
"jest": {
  "roots": [
    "test"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "node",
    "vue"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/"
  ]
},
```

Any idea what more configuration I need to provide in order to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I added a package called `babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node` and that got things building.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that :) In my case that was already installed and configured by Webpacker. I ended up needing to install babel-bridge: `yarn add --dev babel-core@bridge` then things ran as expected.